# What is the role of syntax in semantic role labling?

Tags: computational-linguistics, nlp

For semantic role labeling process, is it enough to just using some corpora like FrameNet and PropBank, or we must have some syntactic annotated corpora using dependency grammar?

Comment: Can you explain a little bit? Do you have a specific language in mind?

Comment: It may or may not be enough, depending on what kinds of semantic roles you want to label, why you want to label them, and how accurate you need the labels to be. Also what software you're using. But very little syntax is required for something like 70% accuracy (and probably much higher nowadays), if you're using the right techniques and if you have good training data.

Comment: I need SRL to extract all information from the text and my question is language independent.